# Konva scale down group

Tags: konvajs

I have an 850x600px Konva stage, and a picture created with lots of SVG images. I want to try to scale down the whole stage/layer/group for it to fit in a phone screen.

- I´ve tried to set the scale to less than 1 (Example: 0.5) but I don´t seem to get it to work.

Which would be the best approach to achieve this?

**Config example:**

`var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width:  850,
  height: 600,
  scale: 0.5
});`

Comment: How are you setting scale? Can you make a demo?

Comment: Are you calling layer.draw() after scaling? Can you post a cut down code sample that shows the issue?

Comment: I am setting the scale in the config of the stage at the beginning, before drawing anything. @lavrton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set `scale` to `0.5`. You need to use:

`scale: {x: 0.5, y: 0.5}`

Or you can use this:

```
scaleX: 0.5,
scaleY: 0.5
```

*Note: I am going to add a warning for invalid values for scale and some other properties in Konva v3.*

Comment: Thanks, that was it.